# Determine when a NSWindow is closing versus leaving full screen

Tags: objective-c, macos, nswindow, nsnotifications

I have a `NSWindow` that goes into full screen. My `NSWindowController` is an observer of the `NSWindowWillCloseNotification` notification.

I would like to do something special when the window is closed (As in the user presses the red X button in the top left hand corner) but I also get the `NSWindowWillCloseNotification` notification when the user leaves full screen mode, in which case I do not want anything to happen.

Is there a way to determine inside of the selector I set up to be called when I observe the `NSWindowWillCloseNotification` notification? At the point my selector is called, the `NSWindow` has already left full screen, so I cannot check if it is full screen or not. Also the `NSNotifications`'s UserInfo dictionary is nil.

Thanks,

Will

Comment: You should not be getting `NSWindowWillCloseNotification` when the window exits full-screen. How did you determine that? Did you perhaps cross wires with the `NSWindowWillExitFullScreenNotification` or `NSWindowDidExitFullScreenNotification` notifications?

Comment: Definitely sure I was getting that notification, but not for my own window! Check the answer to see it was a `NSToolbarFullScreenWindow`!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out I was getting the notification from a window that wasn't my `NSWindowController`'s window!

Printing out the notification that I was receiving we can see that I was getting the `NSWindowWillCloseNotification` call for a `NSToolbarFullScreenWindow`:

`NSConcreteNotification 0x6080002578b0 {name = NSWindowWillCloseNotification; object = <NSToolbarFullScreenWindow: 0x100d57f50>}`

I should have wrote my observer method like this, rather than passing `nil` for object:

`[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
selector:@selector(handleWindowWillClose:)
name:NSWindowWillCloseNotification
object:self.window];`